# Error in getting results from the query in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

im new in using codeigniter and pdo functions, what im trying to do with my code is to get the session data of the user in the model that has `validate()` function then pass it on to the controller that has `verify()` function and then show the session data (username) in the dashboard, but what im getting is an empty username:

```
"Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1562764863 [logged_in] => 1 [username] => )"
```

I'm quite stuck with this one and any help will be greatly appreciate.

"Model"

```
function validate()
{
    $arr['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
    $arr['password'] = ($this->input->post('password'));
    return $this->db->get_where('students',$arr)->row();
    $this->db->close();
}
```

---

"Controller"

```
public function verify()
{
    $this->load->model('student/Studentinfo_model');
    $check = $this->Studentinfo_model->validate();
    if ($check) {

        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

        $user=$this->Studentinfo_model->validate();

        redirect('student/dashboard');

    } else {
        redirect('student');
    }
}



public function dashboard()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $this->load->view('login-templates/header');
        $this->load->view('student/dashboard');
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    }
    else {
         redirect(site_url(student));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out by trying some of the solutions here, below is my new code.

Controller

```
public function verify()
{
    $this->load->model('student/Studentinfo_model');
    $query = $this->Studentinfo_model->validate();

    if ($query)
    {
        $data = array(
            'user' => $query->user, 
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('student/dashboard');

    } else {
        redirect('student');
    }
}
```

Model

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('user', $this->input->post('user'));
    $this->db->where('pass', $this->input->post('pass'));
    $query = $this->db->get('students');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```